# Transforming RDD to List of Map

Tags: java, lambda, spark-streaming, anonymous-function, rdd

I need to transform each RDD to a NavigableMap and store in `List<NavigableMap<byte[], List<Map<String, String>>>>` in an anonymous function. I am doing work on a `JavaPairDStream<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> puts`.

What I have so far:

```
puts.foreachRDD(r ->
    List<NavigableMap<byte[], List<Cell>>> l = r.map(t ->
        t._2().getFamilyCellMap()).collect();
    return null;
});
```

This throws a NotSerializableException at `.collect()` because `Cell` is not serializable.

So I need to somehow transform `Cell` to a `Map<String, String` in the anonymous function and return `List<NavigableMap<byte[], List<Map<String, String>>>>` for me to use `.collect()`.

Not having much Java 8 experience, I am pretty much stuck at this point. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up going about it. I needed `primitives` before `collecting`. I was trying to collect the return value of the `.getFamilyCellMap()` which is a `map` and it was not `serializable`.

Then I turned it back into a `map` before the `assertions`.

Here is the `Java` code:

```
puts.foreachRDD(r -> {
        List<String> l = r.flatMap(t -> {
                    Collection<List<Cell>> collection = t._2().getFamilyCellMap().values();
            return collection.stream()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(CellUtil::cloneValue))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }).collect();

        //Mapping for testing
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map1 = objectMapper.readValue(l.get(1), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
        Map<String, Object> map2 = objectMapper.readValue(l.get(2), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});

        System.out.println(map1);
        Assert.assertEquals(map1.get("attribute1").toString(), expected1);
        //etc
        System.out.println(map2);
        Assert.assertEquals(map2.get("attribute2").toString(), expected2);
        //etc
    }
    return null;
});
```

Hope this helps someone in need.